# Why can't I get Watershed Ridge Lines when I use watershed in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, image-segmentation, watershed

As mentioned in the title, I need to use watershed for image segmentation. And I follow the instruction provided by https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/marker-controlled-watershed-segmentation.html and would like to apply it on my MRI images, but when I calculate the background markers, watershed function returns all numbers within the matrix as 1, so my watershed line does not exist, and I am not sure what the reason is. Here is my code:

```
bw = imbinarize(Iobrcbr); % Iobrcbr represents opening-closing reconstruction
D = bwdist(bw);           % computes the distence between background and forground
DL = watershed(D);        
bgm = DL == 0;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're missing some operations. You could look at some examples in the documentation for that function: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/watershed.html

Comment: I think that when I use watershed, regions with the same pixels correspond to the same label and there should be a clear dividing line between the different areas. For example, as shown in the bw diagram, when using watershed, the background and foreground should both be the same color, and there should be a clear line of demarcation between them.

Comment: What I’m saying is that you’re applying the operations wrong. Look at the documentation that I linked. It shows how to do what you want to do. You need to invert the binary image before applying `bwdist`, and you need to invert the distance transform before applying the watershed.